# Is this a grammar mistake? I got this from the USA Today website

Tags: grammatical-number, be

I just came across this paragraph:

> There **is** so many incredible women that nobody can agree on which one are the best ones. Just for your pleasure and to make everyone happy we have agreed on a list of the 23 most beautiful women.

Why did the write use "is" and not "are"? the word women is a plural word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The same question was posted in ELL, [There is or there are?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77992/there-is-or-there-are).

Comment: @Mari-LouA After reading [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), we seem to have two options, 1) close it as "duplicate" of your linked questions, or 2) close it as "duplicate" of ELL question.

Comment: I could find no evidence that this quotation is taken from an American news website, instead the citation appears to have been replicated many times across different sites. I found this page http://tubead.net/channel/UCoy_AH7QnetRyP0aczgsr7w where the description is identical, and it says the video clip was posted 3 weeks ago. I have not clicked on the video as it looks a bit suspicious to me.Here is another page with the same words exactly, it is from an Indian English website: http://news.priyo.com/2016/01/03/10-most-beautiful-women-world-554720.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was previously posted on http://ell.stackexchange.com/, and the cited source has not been verified.

Comment: This is covered by the duplicate. However, *which one are" is a far more egregious error.

Comment: And that quote does not appear in USA Today. Plenty of other places, but not USA Today.

Comment: My bad. I double checked. It was a sponsored content from USA Today.

Comment: http://www.risottop.com/en/cheesy/the-15-most-beautiful-women-in-the-world/?utm_medium=taboola-en&utm_source=taboola&utm_content=acv0026&utm_source=taboola-en&utm_medium=referral&utm_term=usatodaydemo&utm_campaign=TAB_EN-ROW_d_Safeold08c

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is a grammatical error. The phrase "which one are the best ones" is also ungrammatical - "one" is singular, while "are" suggests plural.

> There is so many incredible women that nobody can agree on **which one are the best ones**.

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right, it is an error.

**Upon @Mari-Lou A's pedantic suggestion:**

The colloquial version of the same sentence would look something like this:

> There's so many incredible women that nobody can agree [...]

Comment: No, it's not. It's colloquial, and very common in speech. And your post should have been left as a comment. How does this answer the question. **"Why did they writers use "is" and not "are"?**

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I beg to differ. "There's so many incredible women ..." would be colloquial. The above example (no contraction) is just plain wrong.

Comment: I agree the contracted form is more common, and your comment above would already improve your answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Have it your way. ... Excessive pedantry should be punished by spanking in a public place at noon.

Comment: Wow, no one has ever called my suggestions pedantic before :) I'm quite chuffed.

Comment: @Ricky - "There's so many incredible women" is also just plain wrong / an error. It might be *common*, but then so is "Banana's 25p" down at the market. "There're so many incredible women" would be both a colloquial contraction and correct.